# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[Total Babies]": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

I attempting to use python to find out how may babies were born in a certain year but am receiving the following error
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[Total Babies]": syntax error

attached below is the code

```
   query = """
            SELECT sum(b[Total Babies]) AS TotalBoys, sum(g[Total Babies]) AS TotalGirls 
            FROM BOYS b JOIN GIRLS g ON b.RANK = g.RANK
        """
c.execute(query)
res = c.fetchone()[0]
num_boys = int(res["TotalBoys"])
num_girls = int(res["TotalGirls"])
num_babies = num_boys + num_girls
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need a period `.` between the table name and the column name thus try using :-

```
query = """
        SELECT sum(b.[Total Babies]) AS TotalBoys, sum(g.[Total Babies]) AS TotalGirls 
        FROM BOYS b JOIN GIRLS g ON b.RANK = g.RANK
    """
```

Comment: num_boys = int(res["TotalBoys"])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable  Now I am attempting to add the string - any suggestions

Comment: The first question was answered and thank you for that